# COM port communication using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, serial-port, pos-for-.net

I am given a project where we want to develop a POS  based web application using asp.net.

I have already looked at POS for net and its a wel-known fact that due framework changes, POS.net needs some config file setting changes. My target framework is 4.5, and so far I don't know how many more libraries are depreciated.

I tried to create some sample applications for Proof-of-concept, I tired ActiveX components, SL4/5 applications to read client machine's COM ports. Since its a development env, I even tried accessing webserver's COM ports.

These applications have their own drawbacks. I also want to mention that since the development is under controlled environment, security settings( for ActiveX) isn't a issue.

1) Using ActiveX restricts the client machines to Windows OS. There is an option to created browser plugins using NAPI, but I couldn't get further with it as it has its own learning curve and the programming is in pyton.
2) Silverlight OOB( out of browser) application seemed promising, but the sample from 
[codeplex](http://www.interopcom.codeplex.com) didn't work in all scenarios

Am I missing out on something?

Please note I have already studied WSPOS implementation.

So far the applications which we have seen that can access client machine's COM ports download a JAR file. The team is finally at a stage where they are concluding that this can be done using JAVA and not C#/.net.

Please let me know what basic point I am missing.

Comment: Can' t you just use the WMI Library?

Comment: Hi Mobstaa, I had a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation). But I am still not sure how that that help me in the given scenario?

Answer (score 0):

How much control do you have over the client machine?  You could write a Windows Service that your web server would interface with.  You would just have to know what terminal your user is logged in from.

Comment: Hi Brian, That Approach will be implementing WSPOS